# In C++, how to control the flow of cin to cout

Tags: c++, string, cin

Image a console program with a interactive prompt.

A user's command is logically split by semicolon.

Here is the simplified code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  bool exit = false;
  string line;
  string input_str;

  do {
    cout << "propmt> " << flush;

    while (getline(cin, line) && !line.empty()) {
      if (!input_str.empty()) {
        input_str += " ";
      }
      input_str += line;

      auto size = input_str.find_first_of(';');

      // find a semicolon
      if (size != string::npos) {
        /* some code deal with part of string before semicolon */
        cout << "\nsample output\nsample output\nsample output\n" << endl;

        input_str.erase(0, size + 1);
        if (!input_str.empty()) {
          cout << "     -> " << flush;
        } else {
          cout << "propmt> " << flush;
        }
      }
    } // getline loop
  } while (!exit);

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is when input is like this (Note: only one return key in this input).

And users just copy and paste it into the command line, not input it by hand.

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAA; BBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBB;
```

My program's output is:

```
propmt> AAAAAAAAAAAAA; BBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBB;
sample output
sample output
sample output

     ->
```

But I want the this part `BBBBBBBBBBBBB;` showed after my sample output.

It should be like this:

```
propmt> AAAAAAAAAAAAA; BBBBBBBBBB
sample output
sample output
sample output

     -> BBBBBBBBBBBBB;
```

And then when user input another Enter key, the program could deal with the whole `B` command and show the result.

Comment: That's just part of how console echoing works, unless you want to get more direct control with a library like curses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand why this happens: data *does not* flow from `cin` to `cout`.  You can see this clearly if you run your program with standard input or standard output redirected from/to file.

Instead, the display of user input is a feature provided by the *terminal* (or whatever) your program is running in. The C++  standard library provides no functionality for controlling this behavior — you will instead need to use a third party library (e.g. ncurses, or whatever Windows uses) to tell the terminal not to echo user input.

Comment: Is there any system call in linux that could control this behavior?

Comment: @Christophe: No idea; ncurses is, AFAIK, the standard way to manipulate the terminal in linux.